# Stream request body in Koa

Tags: node.js, stream, koa, nodejs-stream

I know that I can pass a stream into the *response* body in Koa:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { Context } from 'koa';

const routeHandler = async (ctx: Context): Promise<void> => {
  const stream = fs.createReadStream('path/to/response.png');
  ctx.response.set('Content-type', 'image/png');
  ctx.body = stream;
};
```

But let's say I have a large *request* body. Can I do something like this?

```
import { Context } from 'koa';

const routeHandler = async (ctx: Context): Promise<void> => {
  const stream = ctx.reqest.body; // ???

  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    stream
      .on('data', (chunk) => {
        doSomethingWithChunk(chunk);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        ctx.body = 'Done!';
        resolve();
      })
      .on('error', reject)
  });      
};
```

I can't find any documentation around this in [koaja/bodyparser](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser). The purpose of this would be to have a large request body but not fill up the memory on the server.

Comment: Here you can find an answer that shows how to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571054/koa2-how-to-write-to-response-stream/51616217#51616217

Comment: @SebastianHildebrandt that seems to be streaming to the response, not from the request?